# Django - {% load url from future %} yields error "'url' is not a valid tag library"

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to reuse the [template shown here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) as a basis for my login page but when I run it I get this error:

```
'url' is not a valid tag library
```

Is there some special setting I need to do?

The offending line in the template is:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

I'm on Django 1.2 if it matters.

Comment: `{% load url from future %}` removed in Django 1.9, so you'll get the same error again if you're on a too recent version ;)

Comment: @rednaw alternative?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel well, 1.9 is the future compared to 1.3, so you don't need it ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`1.3 docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

vs

[**`1.2 docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

There is no `{% load url from future %}` until django 1.3.

use this from the [**`1.2 docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @Cerin rednaw commented on the answer: Quoting `{% load url from future %}` removed in Django 1.9, so you'll get the same error again if you're on a too recent version ;)

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel, The solution to to change it to `{% load url from future_or_past %}`

Answer (score 23):

In django 1.9 the url tag is loaded by default so you can simply remove the load statement.

`` RemovedInDjango19Warning: Loading the `url` tag from the `future` library is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Use the default `url` tag instead. ``